# ubuntu crashes during bootup if Nouveau drivers are not configured

Tags: 16.04, nouveau

I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS and I am facing issue with the installation of Nvidia drivers. I read over the internet that to successfully install nvidia drivers I need to either blacklist nouveau drivers or uninstall them. Since 'nouveau' driver is configured in the kernel, so I built a new kernel image with initramfs. I configured the kernel without nouveau driver. But during bootup I see the text messages for few seconds and then the screen goes black and then the system shuts down by itself without showing me anything on console.

Has anyone seen this issue ?
Is there something I am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting kernel boot parameter `nomodeset` fixes the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the best performance out of your GPU, you should be using the drivers from Nvidia. It is easy to do this in Ubuntu. Install from the [PPA by Graphics Driver Team](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) if you want the latest drivers.

Follow along if you need help installing from the PPA.

1. Add the PPA:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
   ```
2. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Search for the latest drivers:

   ```
   apt-cache search nvidia-graphics-drivers
   ```
4. Install the latest driver from the list (currently `nvidia-graphics-drivers-367`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nvidia-graphics-drivers-367
   ```

That should do the job.

Comment: what has this to do with my post ?

Comment: @Monku this is how I installed Nvidia Drivers on a friend's laptop because he wanted to do some stuff (CUDA) that the opensource driver for the card does not support. I thought it would help you.